# What causes "an unknown compilation problem occurred"?

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

When trying to compile my project using Maven, I get the following error: `An unknown compilation problem occurred`.

I tried running the following command to get more details on the error, but I still can't figure it out: `mvn -e -X clean install`

This is the log I got:

```java
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] app ................................................ SUCCESS [  2.033 s]
[INFO] models ............................................. SUCCESS [  4.418 s]
[INFO] authorization-db ................................... SUCCESS [  1.654 s]
[INFO] test-utils ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.721 s]
[INFO] clients ............................................ SUCCESS [  7.412 s]
[INFO] data-access ........................................ FAILURE [  3.289 s]
[INFO] templating ......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] guice-vertx ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] routing ............................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] frontend-tests ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 19.756 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-06-18T11:00:07+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 53M/190M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project data-access: Compilation failure
[ERROR] An unknown compilation problem occurred
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project data-access: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
An unknown compilation problem occurred

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :data-access
```

EDIT: This is the `pom.xml` file of the `data-access` module:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.some.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>data-access</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.some.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>authorization-db</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.englishtown.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>testtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-unit</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-codetrans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-rx-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.some.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>clients</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.some.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>models</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.some.app</groupId>
      <artifactId>test-utils</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
      <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>


  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

EDIT 2: Maven compiler plugin configuration on root `pom.xml`:

```xml
...

<properties>
  <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
  <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

...

<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>${java.version}</source>
    <target>${java.version}</target>
  </configuration>
</plugin>

...
```

To note that this compilation problem started happening after I migrated the Java version in the project from 1.8 to 11.

Comment: Try to separately compile data-access module and look for any errors.

Comment: Could you add the `pom.xml` from `data-access` ?

Comment: @Ajinkya Did that. Got the exact same log.

Comment: Please share pom.xml for that module

Comment: Check the edit I made

Comment: What is maven compiler plugin configuration? Probably present in your parent pom.

Comment: Check my second edit

Comment: I had the same problem tonight. At last, it was the resolution of an empty diamond operator that causes the pain. I found the problem switching back the compatibility to version 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue. I was able to get rid of this issue after removing

**<compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>**

line from maven compiler plugin configuration in pom.xml file.

maven-compiler-plugin configuration before removing above line:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArgument>-Werror</compilerArgument>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

maven-compiler-plugin configuration after removing above line:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This solved my problem which was bugging since last week. Thanks @Pramod

Answer (score 2):

You are using old version of maven plugin (3.1) to compile your code. To compile java 11 code using maven please use maven plugin with below configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>11</release>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought about too right after I added my second edit. But I tried that and the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

Follow steps are given below,

```
1) Run as Maven clean
2) Go to Project(top bar in eclipse) and clean it
3) Run as Maven install
```

(Sometimes need to clean twice in eclipse before run mvn install)
Hope this will help.

Comment: I forgot to mention. I'm using Intellij.

Comment: clean you can perform in intelliJ too, Can you try same

Comment: Tried cleaning the project twice and then compiling. Same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the maven compiler plugin and it is a fight to use correct version compatibility between maven, JDK, and this plug-in.
In my case, reason of the issue was, I was using jdk-8u291-windows-x64 instead of jdk-8u211-windows-x64.